# How to read in a file into a specific format

Tags: java, loops

I have a file containing some data that looks like this.

```
[Todays date]  Some text
some more text
even more text
[A different date]  Some text 
[Another different date]  More text
Final text block
```

I'd like to read this into a `List<String>` if possible but I don't want to have it exactly like the file. Ideally the `List<String>` would look like.

```
[Todays date] some text some more text even more text
[A different date] some text
[Another different date] More text Final text block
```

If the line of text doesn't start with a squared bracket I want to just concatenate that line to the above line. I can read it in normally using this code. I tried to use String.startsWith but I couldn't figure it out.

```
    List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SystemOut.log"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line!=null) {
        testList.add(line);
        line=br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
```

I'm looking for either a change to this method that will make it read it in to my desired format or maybe a method that will act on my `List<String>` and sort this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution (3rd attempt) which (hopefully) will work better with large files as it avoids reading the whole file into buffer:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = "[04/06/2021]  Some text\n" +
                "some more text\n" +
                "even more text\n" +
                "[01/01/2020]  Some text \n" +
                "[31/12/2020]  More text\n" +
                "Final text block";


        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
            br.lines().forEach(
                    line -> {
                        if (testList.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("[")) {
                            testList.add(line + " ");
                        } else {
                            testList.set(
                                    testList.size() - 1,
                                    testList.get(testList.size() - 1) + line + " ");
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        testList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

I came up with this tedious method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = "[04/06/2021]  Some text\n" +
                "some more text\n" +
                "even more text\n" +
                "[01/01/2020]  Some text \n" +
                "[31/12/2020]  More text\n" +
                "Final text block";

        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
            String nextLine = br.readLine();
            StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(nextLine + " ");
            while (nextLine != null) {
                nextLine = br.readLine();
                if (nextLine != null) {
                    if (nextLine.startsWith("[")) {
                        testList.add(currentLine.toString());
                        currentLine = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                currentLine.append(nextLine).append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (currentLine.length() > 0) {
                testList.add(currentLine.toString());
            }
        }
        testList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

If you can move away from your loop, a better/simpler approach would be:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = "[04/06/2021]  Some text\n" +
                "some more text\n" +
                "even more text\n" +
                "[01/01/2020]  Some text \n" +
                "[31/12/2020]  More text\n" +
                "Final text block";

        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] inputs = input.split("\\n");
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(inputs[0] + " ");
        for (int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].startsWith("[")) {
                testList.add(currentLine.toString());
                currentLine = new StringBuilder();
            }
            currentLine.append(inputs[i]).append(" ");
        }
        testList.add(currentLine.toString());
        testList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Output:

```
[04/06/2021]  Some text some more text even more text 
[01/01/2020]  Some text  
[31/12/2020]  More text Final text block
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I've ran it and it is working exactly as I intended. One question I do have though is that my input comes from a file? Is there a simple way to just read my file in as one huge string so I can use your method or do I need to read it in as a `List<String>` (I have this already) and then turn it into a big string from there?

Comment: Actually on second thought you probably don't want to read the entire file if it is huge. Better to do it line by line. Should be possible to improve the first approach to make it more concise.

Comment: @ConnorGill I think my 3rd attempt is much better than the previous 2. It's a lot cleaner and doesn't need to hold the whole file in memory.